# Resizing A Div/Class With New AJAX Appended Content Height, When Height Of Page Already Set OnLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, height, append

I've spent nearly 24 hours on this issue, so I'm hoping I can rely on someone that has a better handle of javascript and jquery to help.

The situation is this. I have a slideshow-type setup (coda slider 2 by Niall Doherty) that essentially auto-adjusts the height of each panel/page based on the content that is on the page. That works great, except for when I have dynamic data coming in, in this specific case, I am appending a div via jquery POST Ajax so comments can appear without a reload needed. The problem I'm running into is that since the height is already pre-set onload, the new content doesn't appear, or rather appears below the visible content (overflow is hidden), so I need to resize the main div/class to take into account the new info - and all on the press of the "new comment" button.

I think I came up with a solution where I use the jquery height function to measure the height of the container div I am using for the slide and then adjust the height of that div accordingly, but I believe the js is executing as the button is pused, and thus when the new comment is finally appended via the ajax call, it used the old height and not the new height.

Any help would be appreciated in either getting my rough hack to work, or if you have better ideas on how to handle this more gracefully.

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm shooting blind without some code, but my guess would be that you'll want to execute the solution you came up with *after* the ajax call completes. So,

```
$.post("action", {
    data
}, function () {
    // DO THE CALCULATION HERE
});
```

That will execute after the AJAX call has completed.

Comment: Hey Adrian, here's some code:

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data:  "id=" + id + "&info=" + info,
  success: function(html){
   $("#new).append(html).
  }
 });

I'm using jquery and had the code to measure height in the success function, but doesn't seem to capture the height of the new info, just the info at the very moment I press the button. I'm assuming the place where you have // DO THE CALCULATION HERE is the same as the success function - in which case any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: You can also try creating a custom jQuery function to calculate the height:
    jQuery.fn.calculateHeight = function() {
     // Calculate Height here
     return this; // Returns jQuery to enable chaining
    };

    $("#new").append(html).calculateHeight();

That will assure that the calculations are done after the html is done appending.

Comment: Adrian - good stuff. I'll give it a shot and let you know what happens. Def appreciate the insight/help! Thanks.

Comment: Adrian, does this look right?

    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "ajax.php", data: "id=" + id + "&info=" + info, success: function(html){ $("#new).append(html); var newheight = $('.container').height(); $('.container').css("height", newheight); } })

So far, when I try this, it seems to all execute at the same time, getting the height and then setting it, but seemingly before the new content is added... almost like it needs to wait a second before checking the new height - so nothing changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Adrian, I also tried creating the custom function but and putting the function call after the append(html), but still running into the same issue where it's calculating the height at the same time that it's processing... this time I'm at least getting a value of "1" additional pixel, but it's still happening too quickly that it doesn't wait for the rest of the content to load, so the height adjustment is inaccurate. I guess another option would be to delay() it, but I've tried that too and it doesn't work.

Comment: The content you're loading in, does it include images that might not have loaded yet?

Comment: No, it's just text. I'm appending comments to a page contained within divs. From what I can tell it's more of a timing issue, but I'm not sure. If I separate the function out, and run it separately after the content is loaded i have no problem. But, I'm trying to get all the actions done on the click of the button.

Comment: Yeah, Pete, I'm not sure what's going on here. Performing the calculation after the `.append()` really should assure that the timing is right.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the help. I'll keep trying to dig into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this would be to call the height adjustment function from a script tag inside loaded html. If the content loaded via ajax is also in your control, that is.

Comment: It is in my control, can you elaborate further?... I'm kinda new to the whole javascript/jquery world :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relevant bits of your JavaScript, it's difficult to know what you are aiming to do. However, you can execute a function once the AJAX call has completed successfully by using the "success:" option on the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function call. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

This callback function is where you should put your resize code.

Sorry, just noticed you were using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). That too has a callback function where you should put your resize code.

Comment: Hey Neil, Thanks for the response. Here is what my code looks like: 

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data:  "id=" + id + "&info=" + info,
  success: function(html){
   $("#new).append(html).
  }
 });

I tried to put the jquery height function to capture the new height within the callback (in the success function), but it seems to only capture the height at that moment, and before the new data appends... since it seems like there is a small delay before the new info is appended. Am I just doing something wrong and it should work??